# Configure Dynamic Proxies in GluonFx

Tags: java, graalvm, gluon, graalvm-native-image, gluonfx

I have a server application based on GluonFX. This one uses jetty server. When I run native build I get such exception:

> Caused by: com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.UnsupportedFeatureError: Proxy
> class defined by interfaces [interface
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.ExtendedUriInfo, interface
> org.glassfish.hk2.api.ProxyCtl] not found. Generating proxy classes at
> runtime is not supported. Proxy classes need to be defined at image
> build time by specifying the list of interfaces that they implement.
> To define proxy classes use
> -H:DynamicProxyConfigurationFiles= and -H:DynamicProxyConfigurationResources=
> options.

If I understood correctly I need add dynamic proxies for interfaces for **ExtendedUriInfo** and **ProxyCtl**
And I found how do it for graalvm build:

https://www.graalvm.org/latest/reference-manual/native-image/guides/configure-dynamic-proxies/

But How Can I do it if I use GluonFX ?

Comment: Run `mvn gluonfx:runagent`, explore the application, and then try `mvn gluonfx:build gluonfx:nativerun` again.